# How to run a class anytime a editor page receive focus on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to run a class everytime editor page  receive  focus, something like prompt message when a class source has changed outside eclipse? Can a plug-in editor or extension do this work?

Answer (score 4):

The FAQ "[How do I find out what view or editor is selected?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_view_or_editor_is_selected%3F)" can help you call your class when the Editor is active (which is when you can test if it has focus as well), by [using a `IPartService`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/IPartService.java.htm):

> Two types of listeners can be added to the part service:

- `IPartListener`
- and the [poorly named `IPartListener2`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.java.htm).

> You should always **use this second one as it can handle part-change events on parts that have not yet been created because they are hidden in a stack behind another part**.
>   This listener will also tell you when a part is made visible or hidden or when an editor's input is changed:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = ...;
   //the active part
   IWorkbenchPart active = page.getActivePart();
   //adding a listener
   IPartListener2 pl = new IPartListener2() {
      public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference ref)
         System.out.println("Active: "+ref.getTitle());
      }
      ... other listener methods ...
   };
   page.addPartListener(pl);
```

Note: [`IWorkbenchPage`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.java.htm) implements `IPartService` directly.
You can also access an activation service by [using `IWorkbenchWindow.getPartService()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchWindow.java.htm#88).

Answer (score 0):

> I am click Toolbar or Button to get focus which view or editor current working on RCP eclipse

```
//class:Current_Workbech  extends AbstractHandler to execute() method

public class Current_Workbech  extends AbstractHandler{

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IPartService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

        //MessageDialog box open to get title which view or editor focus and current working

        MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(
                event).getShell(), "Current Workbench Window", service.getActivePart().getTitle()+"");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @luiz  this answer is usefull...have a nice day