# Eclipse RCP: How can I update a view when the selected editor changes?

Tags: view, hyperlink, editor, eclipse-rcp, listener

This should be quite a common problem, but I couldn't find anything helpful on the topic.

We are developing an application with Eclipse RCP. The application shows data in an editor of which usually multiple instances are open. In an additional view you can edit the editor-values. When the values are changed in the view they are updated in the editor and it's dirty flag is set.

So far it works fine. What we're missing is: **When another editor instance gets the focus, our view should show the data of this editor.**

I managed to do that for two views. The second view is sucessfully updated using a `TableViewer` as selection Provider and registering a `SelectionListener` in the other view. I tried the same thing for the editor using a Viewer I subclassed from `ContentViewer`, but it didn't work.

Can this approach be working?
Or do I need a different approach on the problem?

Comment: You've given us no context as to what you're talking about, so noone's answering.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work out"? What stops you from refreshing your subclassed Viewer in response to a selection listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you cerealk, that was exactly what I needed. :-)

### Update the View when another Editor is selected

```
public class myView {

    // Create an IPartListener2 
    IPartListener2 pl = new IPartListener2() {

        // If the Editor I'm interested in was updated ...
             public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {
                  IWorkbenchPart part = ref.getPart(true);
                  if (part instanceof DetailEditor) {

                  // ... update the view
                  Contact contactFromSelectedEditor = ((DetailEditor) part).detailComposite.contact;
                  detailComposite.update(contactFromSelectedEditor);
                  }
             }
        ...
        }

    // Add the IPartListener2 to the page   
    IWorkbenchPage page = this.getSite().getPage();
    page.addPartListener(pl);

}
```

### Why use an IPartListener2 instead of an IPartListener

The [IPartListener2](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.html) replaces IPartListener with 3.5.

As explained in this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294738/how-to-run-a-class-anytime-a-editor-page-receive-focus-on-eclipse):

> **You should always use IPartListener2 as it can handle part-change events on parts that have not yet been
>   created because they are hidden in a stack behind another part.**
>
> This
>   listener will also tell you when a part is made visible or hidden or
>   when an editor's input is changed.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can subclass your view from [PageBookView](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/PageBookView.html) and then provide special adapter for your editor. Outline View is implemented using this approach.